# Adding noise to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vector, noise

So say I'm trying to create a 100-sample dataset that follows a certain line, maybe 2x+2.  And I want the values on my X-axis to range from 0-1000.  To do this, I use the following.

```
X = np.random.random(100,1) * 1000
Y = (2*X) + 2
data = np.hstack(X,Y)
```

The hstack gives me the array with corresponding x and y values.  That part works.  But if I want to inject noise into it in order to scatter the datapoints further away from that 2x+2 line...that's what I can't figure out.

Say for example, I want that Y array to have a standard deviation of 20.  How would I inject that noise into the y values?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but have you tried adding [`numpy.random.normal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html)`(scale=20,size=100)` to `Y`?  You can even write

```
Y=numpy.random.normal(2*X+2,20)
```

and do it all at once (and without repeating the array size).

Comment: This seems to have exactly the effect I was looking for.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

To simulate noise use a normally distributed random number generator like [`np.random.randn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html).

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
X = np.linspace(0, 1000, 100)
Y = (2*X) + 2 + 20*np.random.randn(100)
data = np.hstack((X.reshape(100,1),Y.reshape(100,1)))
```

[image]